# Webhosting with custom database choice

Tags: web-hosting, database, custom-software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am trying to find somewhere to host a website which uses OrientDB as its database. My budget doesn't stretch to a dedicated server where I can configure everything as I need it. Rather, I am hoping to find somewhere, ideally UK based, that will allow me to install/install for me OrientDB on their server, that is of the normal shared server variety. Is anybody able to point me in a good direction for this please (whilst UK is preferable it is not essential)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [NuvolaBase](http://www.nuvolabase.com/site/faq.html) allows OrientDB hosting, there are some useful articles over [technobits which may help you find NoSQL hosting](http://www.technobits.net/articles/25427/nosql-hosting-services/)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen NuvolaBase before. Fingers crossed that NoSQL hosting services improve!

Comment: @churchill614 no worries, there are a few hosts which specialise in database only hosting, this might be an avenue to think about.